# Yii Cbreadcrumbs - how to customize Cbreadcrumbs routes?

Tags: yii

Here's what I have on the **layout** page:

```
<?php
 $this->widget('zii.widgets.CBreadcrumbs', array(
   'links'=>$this->breadcrumbs,
   'separator'=>' > ',
   'homeLink' => CHtml::link('Initial Page', Yii::app()->homeUrl)
));
?>
```

Here's what I have on the **view**:

```
$this->breadcrumbs=array(Yii::t('srr', 'Routes'));
```

Here's the folder and files structure:

```
views/activity/index
views/activity/route
```

When the user is on index he/she sees the breadcrumb like this:

```
 Initial Page > Activity
```

When the user is on route he/she sees the breadcrumb like this:

```
 Initial Page > Route
```

**I wish to, when the user is on route page, to have a breadcrumb like this instead:**

```
Initial Page > Activity > Route
```

Route is a static page, but has it's own action (just in case) on activity controller.

**How can we accomplish something like this ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Breadcrumb [`links`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CBreadcrumbs#links-detail) are just like this:

```
'Label'=>'url'
```

So you can do this in the view:

```
$this->breadcrumbs=array(
    'Activity'=>array('index'),
    Yii::t('srr', 'Routes')
);
```